# Cache control header set for xml like html meta tag

Tags: xml, cache-control

Is it possible to set meta tag in xml like `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=120"/>`

I have to get xml feed from my server and set cache control max age that next time copernica email marketing will not send request to my server for xml feed and get xml from cache.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no equivalent of `http-equiv` for general XML files.

Some specific formats include this (for example: [RSS feed: how to recommend an update interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389255/rss-feed-how-to-recommend-an-update-interval)), but for a general solution set the `Cache-Control` headers at the HTTP level. You may be able to use `.htaccess`; see [Implementing cache control using .htaccess on Apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619261/implementing-cache-control-using-htaccess-on-apache-server), for example.